# Starting tomcat in multiple processes

Tags: apache, tomcat7

In IIS I can have one application pool per web application. This would lead to every application to running in its own independent process (One per application pool) and thus isolate those processes from each other. Is there a way to do something similar in apache tomcat? If I am running 10 web applications in tomcat, I want them to run in 10 different processes.

Answer (score 0):

I do that by starting multiple tomcat process, one per app. The setup is not too complicated plus you can manage each app via initd. I never did this with Tomcat 7 but I'm pretty sure this should work:

http://www.nfms4redd.org/downloads/previous/documentation/install/tomcat.html